# How to exclude rows from an aggregate based on the rest of the rows in the aggregate

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I've tried to simplify this a little without removing any pertinent information, so here goes...

I am trying to rewrite a view which currently aggregates data, but based on the aggregate of some of the data it may or may not include other data. For example:

```
;WITH CTE_ExtraFees AS
(
    SELECT AccountID, SUM(Amount) AS TotalAmount
    FROM AccountFees
    WHERE
        FeeType = 'EXTRA' AND
        AccountType = 'P'
    GROUP BY
        AccountID
)
SELECT
    AccountID,
    CASE
        WHEN SUM(F.Amount) > 0 THEN SUM(F.Amount) - XF.TotalAmount
        ELSE SUM(F.Amount)
    END AS FeeAmount
FROM
    AccountFees F
LEFT OUTER JOIN CTE_ExtraFees XF ON XF.AccountID = F.AccountID
GROUP BY
    F.AccountID,
    XF.TotalAmount
```

There's quite a bit more logic on which extra fees are excluded, but I've worked all of that out and the above is the last sticking point for me. I now have something similar to this:

```
SELECT
    AccountID,
    SUM(Amount) AS FeeAmount
FROM
    AccountFees
WHERE
    (
        FeeType <> 'EXTRA' OR
        AccountType <> 'P'
    )
GROUP BY
    AccountID
```

The problem of course is that when the `SUM(Fees) <= 0` I still end up excluding the extra fees.

I'd like to avoid having multiple aggregates performed for performance reasons, so I was hoping to do this all in one aggregation, but I can't seem to come up with anything to accomplish the same logic.

Thanks for any help or suggestions that you can give!

Comment: What does this tricky sentence mean `but based on the aggregate of some of the data it may or may not include other data`? Without sample data I can not get you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
      AccountID
    , FeeAmount =
        CASE WHEN SUM(Amount) > 0
            THEN SUM(Amount) - SUM(CASE WHEN FeeType = 'EXTRA' AND AccountType = 'P' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END)
            ELSE SUM(Amount)
        END
FROM dbo.AccountFees
GROUP BY AccountID
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked for the part that I was struggling with. My criteria also included an EXIST (which I took out for simplicity), which I can't put within the SUM(CASE...) since SQL Server won't accept that. That's a separate issue though, so I might start a new question for that.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
SELECT
    AccountID,
    SUM(
        CASE WHEN FeeType = 'EXTRA' AND AccountType = 'P'
            THEN -1 * Amount
            ELSE Amount
        END
    ) AS FeeAmount
FROM AccountFees
GROUP BY AccountID
```

I think they key part that you may have been missing on this problem is the fact that you can run a Sum function on a case statement, which is used both in my answer and in Devart's answer (which, by the way, I feel more comprehensively encompasses the logic of the original query). The case statement will fire on a row-by-row basis and then provide its results to the sum function, which results in a conditional sum function.

Comment: Thanks. I had thought of using a SUM(CASE...), but hadn't considered embedding them the way that Devart did. The key was the CASE SUM() SUM(CASE...)